# Scrub header for internal servers in Postfix?

Tags: postfix, smtp-headers

We have all internal Centos servers sending mail to 2 outgoing MX servers in our business. I want to scrub the headers on our 2 outgoing MX servers to remove the information from where they originated. I don't know the syntax of this very well and the MAN pages don't give enough examples. I want internal IPs and Hostnames scrubbed from header.

We are using postfix on every server, including our public facing MX servers.

Comment: http://www.void.gr/kargig/blog/2013/11/24/anonymize-headers-in-postfix/

Answer (score 4):

What you want to use is the header_checks rules. You will need to tweak this for your particular servers but this is an example:

```
/^Received:.* \[127\.0\.\.0\1\]\) by \S+\.server\.com \(Postfix\)/ IGNORE
```

See http://www.postfix.org/header_checks.5.html for more details and options.

See for an example post from someone doing the same thing: http://zcentric.com/2013/04/15/remove-internal-hosts-in-postfix/

And this, for someone's comment about whether it's right to do this or not - [postfix remote received header](https://serverfault.com/questions/324841/postfix-remote-received-header?rq=1)  ... to be taken with a grain of salt. Hiding internal relay may not be totally in violation of the RFC. Don't want to debate that, just want to give you various points of view.