# Is extra "Received by" in mail headers bad and can I remove it?

Tags: email, smtp, email-server

I use our own VPS web and mail server to send out a newsletter regularly to 50,000 addresses.

I am trying to improve deliverability and was looking through some of the thousands of bounce emails. One thing I noticed was that there is kind of an extra "Received by" header that I wonder if could cause any problems. One of the bounce messages indicated that it did not accept due to relaying and I wonder if this could be the cause (there is no relaying)?

Here is an excerpt from a sample message:

```
Received: from mydomain.com.au ([x.x.x.x]) by
ipbvo.tcif.telstra.com.au with SMTP; 06 Mar 2014 11:22:13 +1100
Received: from internaldomainname.com ([127.0.0.1]) by mydomain.com.au ;
Thu, 6 Mar 2014 11:22:11 +1100
```

The second line is the one I question. Does the mail server have to indicate this?

The newsletter sending system is written in ASP.NET and uses Jmail .NET to send each email message using the server at 127.0.0.1.

The mail server software in use is Hmailserver.

Also, if it can't be changed, I would like to replace the internaldomainname part that it shows. Would that be a Hmailserver, DNS or network setting?

Comment: Could this be the same as what you are trying to do? http://serverfault.com/questions/576237/scrub-header-for-internal-servers-in-postfix/576238#576238

Comment: I first want to know if this extra header should be there and whether it is harmful, then if so I will want to know hot to remove it, but am using a different mail server to that post. Thank you.

Comment: That header is normal and harmless.

Answer (score 2):

As per [RFC 5321](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5321.txt), s3.7.2,

> When forwarding a message into or out of the Internet environment, a gateway MUST prepend a Received: line, but it MUST NOT alter in any way a Received: line that is already in the header section.

it should be there.  Each mail server (that forwards into or out of the internet environment) should add one, and that (usually) includes the mail server that first receives it from the MUA (the application that generated it).  In this case, as you have noted, your mail server is indicating that the message was generated locally (`127.0.0.1`).

I'm aware that some people filter email based on the content of `Received: from` headers added outside the receiving organisation.  **They are wrong to do so**; the headers cannot be relied on, so any decision about the deliverability of mail based on them will be subject to spoofing.  If you are having trouble with people getting your mail because of those lines, contact the recipient organisation and point out that they're behaving foolishly.

The domain name reflected will be due to local setup on your mail server.  Since you're using asp.net I'm guessing this is a Windows box, so I can't advise you on how to change that; but it will be locally-determined.

**Edit**: John, I read that as meaning "*into, or out of, the public internet*".  Note also that the requirement is predicated on both halves of the message's flight through any given server.  If a server sends a message on to the public internet, it must add a `Received: from` header - even if the reception was from an internal, or even local, server.  Only if a mail server is purely internal to the organisation is it not required to add one.  Even then it may do so, and if it does, no downstream (internet-interacting) server is permitted to change it.

Comment: By Internet does that also include local transferring of the message to the local mail server (on same server)?